# LoadLibraryEx function

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the LoadLibraryEx function however, it fails everytime and does not give me any proper error to know what is going wrong. Here is my code:

```
 HMODULE h;
        h = LoadLibraryEx("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Include\\LMJoin.h", NULL, 0x00000008);
        if(h!=NULL)
        {
            if (::GetModuleHandleExW(0, L"LMJoin.h", &h))
            {
                typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGET_DOMAIN_INFO)(wchar_t const**, wchar_t**, _NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS*);
                PGET_DOMAIN_INFO getDomainInfo = (PGET_DOMAIN_INFO)GetProcAddress(h, "NetGetJoinInformation");
                if (NULL != getDomainInfo)
                {
                    nas = (getDomainInfo)(NULL, &lpNameBuffer, &BufferType);
                }
            }
            FreeLibrary(h);
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE_ERR("LMJoin.h Library could not be loaded\n",GetLastError());
        }
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LoadLibraryEx` is for loading DLL files, not header files. [NetGetJoinInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is in the `Netapi32.dll` DLL. It's declared in `Lmjoin.h (include Lm.h)`.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\LMJoin.h is a header file not a library.